# Is it possible to install Android using OpenIBoot on an iPhone with the limerain/greenp0ison jailbreak?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

What it says on the tin;  I have an iPhone 3GS jailbroken with limera1n, and I'd love to try Android on it. I've installed Bootlace from the OpenIBoot cydia repository, but it claims it can't run on my phone.

Is it possible to get Android running on my phone? If so, how?

Comment: My reputation is too low to create new tags, but I feel that "android openiboot limera1n" are good tags to add to this, if someone wants to do it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to install iDroid on 3gs at this time, only 2g and 3g iphones. My 3g is runnin it great. Sorry bro.