# Can I install a custom OS on iPhone 5s?

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak, firmware, hacking

I got myself an owned iPhone 5s to have some fun. Today I got extra adventurous and would like to try some "unofficial" operating systems like Android and postmarketOS. Unfortunately, a quick search with Google didn't give me much information.

Comment: Hopelessly outdated isn’t a valid reason not to close duplicate questions. See [help]. We put bounties and edit outdated questions to get answers over time.

Comment: See here: https://www.reddit.com/r/jailbreak/comments/dhaza1/request_a_bootlace_alternative_for_the_new/

Comment: Related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16878/is-it-possible-to-install-android-os-on-an-iphone, https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3993/is-it-possible-to-install-android-using-openiboot-on-an-iphone-with-the-limerain, https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34513/can-we-install-android-on-an-iphone-4

Answer (score 1):

Is there an easy switch to jailbreak iPhone 5 that’s documented here - not yet.

May you find a crack or Apple key to sign whatever code you want. Of course, any hardware system could have cracks.

Can you do it? Depends on your skill and research ability and time you devote to the exercise.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread but for anyone looking you are able to install Android on iPhones now thanks to Project Sandcastle.

More info can be found [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/jailbreak/comments/fdg9ao/release_project_sandcastle_android_for_your_iphone/)

Comment: A direct link: https://projectsandcastle.org